# Is there a format code shortcut for Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

In [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) there is a shortcut, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, that re-indents code and fixes comments and blank lines. Is there an equivalent for Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: VS does a subset of what Eclipse does. VS does not fix blank lines, nor reflow comments.  To get the whole enchilada you need reSharper or something like that.

Comment: Why is this tagged with 3 specific versions of Visual Studio, Visual Studio 2010, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: The corresponding for [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) is *[How do you format code in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357)*

Comment: you can press Ctrl + K + F in visual studio to format code. Here are the nice explanation video on Visual Studio shortcuts https://youtu.be/cKULRwEWtsQ

Answer (score 878, accepted):

#### Visual Studio *with* C# *key bindings*

To answer the specific question, in C# you are likely to be using the C# keyboard mapping scheme, which will use these hotkeys by default:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to format the entire document.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to format the selection.

You can change these in menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Environment* → *Keyboard* (either by selecting a different "keyboard mapping scheme", or binding individual keys to the commands "Edit.FormatDocument" and "Edit.FormatSelection").

If you have not chosen to use the C# keyboard mapping scheme, then **you may find the key shortcuts are different**. For example, if you are not using the C# bindings, the keys are likely to be:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (Entire document)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (Selection only)

To find out which key bindings apply in *your* copy of Visual Studio, look in menu *Edit* → *Advanced menu* - the keys are displayed to the right of the menu items, so it's easy to discover what they are on your system.

---

<sub>*(Please do not edit this answer to change the key bindings above to what **your** system has!)*</sub>

Comment: In addition, in the Tools > Options, go to Text Editor > C# > Formatting and you can control how it formats the code.

Comment: These shortcuts (starting with Ctrl+E) are valid for Visual Studio 2005 and 2008 only. Use the shortcuts Ctrl+K+D and Ctrl+K+F to acchive the same in Visual Studio 2010 (if you are using the default configuration).

Comment: Indeed, but for clarity: the C# settings for vs2010 are still as described in my answer.

Comment: It also fixes the code that suddenly wraps into ONLY one line of code. I'm using VS 2012.

Comment: It's bugs me that i couldn't find a way to format only the current line. With MonoDevelop in the options you can set Tab to auto format the current line. In VS 2013 there is no `Edit.FormatLine` in the Keyboard Mapping manager.

When you use Git or Svn formating any other lines than the one you are working on result in a lot of useless changes...

Comment: @madrang - you should be able to use 'format selection' to do that; you'll just have to select the line first. (Or to reduce the impact you can set up your merge/diff tools to ignore whitespace differences)

Comment: you can press Ctrl + K + F in visual studio to format code. Here are the nice explanation video on Visual Studio shortcuts https://youtu.be/cKULRwEWtsQ

Answer (score 127):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (Entire document)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (Selection only)

Comment: I just noticed that they differ. When I format the whole document (`Edit.FormatDocument`) some code cleanup also happens, e.g. I have set `Add/remove braces for single-line control statements` (really bad description because the user has no idea what happens when you activate it^^) so the formatter always changes `if(foo) bar;` to `if(foo) { bar; }`. executing Edit.FormatSelection doesn’t change that. Might be a bug, gonna report it if I cannot find anything.

Comment: Ok, I just realized that it‘s not possible to execute all actions as the user selection can obviously be anything and not include all opening/closing parentheses etc. I still reported it because some actions should still be possible to perform.

Answer (score 48):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (don't lift the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key in between).

Comment: odd, CTRL+K+CTRL+D works (comes up in that status bar that it is recognised but CTRL+K+D does not and does nothing, might have something to do with the editor profile, but I can not remember which option I choose.

Comment: This should be mentioned properly because I had no idea what ctrl+K,ctrl+D meant. I wonder why pressing 2 keys is necessary for something this basic.

Answer (score 28):

Yes, you can use the two-chord hotkey (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> if you're using the General profile) to format your selection.

Other formatting options are under menu *Edit* → *Advanced*, and like all Visual Studio commands, you can set your own hotkey via menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Environment* → *Keyboard* (the format selection command is called `Edit.FormatSelection`).

Formatting doesn't do anything with blank lines, but it will indent your code according to some rules that are usually slightly off from what you probably want.

Comment: If by "slightly off" you mean that the braces for block statements start on a new line, then it is not a problem. That is actually how I prefer it anyway.

Comment: These are the default shortcuts for Visual Studio 2010. For VS 2005 and 2008 use the default shortcuts Ctrl+E+D and Ctrl+E+F.

Comment: It will format the code in the way defined by your settings - the default if you don't configure them, as possible using Tools » Options » Text Editor » CSS (for VS 2012, probably something very similar in previous versions if not the same.)

Answer (score 19):

[ReSharper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#ReSharper_Ultimate) - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Visual Studio 2010 - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Answer (score 13):

Format the entire document:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Answer (score 12):

To align the text in the proper format -

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> for front end pages like `.aspx` or `.cshtml`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> for a `.cs` page

But observe to press all buttons in sequence...

Answer (score 11):

## Simply

For `Visual Studio Code` Use <kbd>ALt + Shift + F</kbd>

for `Visual Studio IDE` Press <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd>

It will beautify/format your entire file.

Comment: when the paying version is worse than the free one...

Answer (score 9):

Most easy, try once

1. Select all codes using :- Ctrl + A
2. Press :- Ctrl + K + D

Comment: True, but why add the same answer again?

Answer (score 5):

Select all text in the document and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the code, and you have "Format Document". In my case it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

[image]

Comment: What version of Visual Studio is the screenshot from?

Comment: @PeterMortensen This is from Visual Studio Code, which isn't what the OP asked about, and therefore doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Nor is this C# code.

Answer (score 2):

Change these shortcuts in Visual Studio

```
Tools → Options → Environment → Keyboard
```

and then change the command

```
"Edit.FormatDocument" or "Edit.FormatSelection"
```

assign the same shortcut `alt + shift +f` as in visual studio code in order to not remember another one and confuse between each other.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2022, it's `Ctrl + K` followed by `Ctrl + D`.