# Difference between Ctrl K + D and Ctrl E + D

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, difference

What is the difference between the Visual Studio 2010 shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>?

Comment: Answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942113/format-code-shortcut-for-vs2010

Answer (score 51):

**Visual Studio WITH C# KEY BINDINGS**

To answer the specific question, in C# you are likely to be using the C# keyboard mapping scheme, which will use these hotkeys by default:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to format the entire document.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to format the selection.

You can change these in Tools > Options > Environment -> Keyboard (either by selecting a different "keyboard mapping scheme", or binding individual keys to the commands "Edit.FormatDocument" and "Edit.FormatSelection").

If you have not chosen to use the C# keyboard mapping scheme, then you may find the key shortcuts are different. For example, if you are not using the C# bindings, the keys are likely to be:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (Entire document)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (Selection only)

To find out which key bindings apply in YOUR copy of Visual Studio, look in the Edit > Advanced menu - the keys are displayed to the right of the menu items, so it's easy to discover what they are on your system.