# How do you format code in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)?

Tags: code-formatting, visual-studio-code

What is the equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> on Windows in Visual Studio for formatting, or "beautifying" code in the Visual Studio Code editor?

Comment: For all those desperately trying to **format XML** (which seems not possible out of the box currently) you can achieve this by installing an extension. I have found [_XML Tools_](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DotJoshJohnson.xml#review-details) to get the job done just fine. _Disclaimer: I am not the author nor related to this project..._

Comment: While VSCode has much fewer menu options than VS (new trend?), it has extensive info and tutorials under the HELP menu, which may have answered this question.

Comment: For all those struggling to get the formatting work even after trying the valid combinations in Visual Studio Code, don't forget to select the appropriate programming language type, it is at the bottom right in visual studio code window next to that smiley. Once you do that I found it works out of the box and you don't need any additional plugin to format code.

Answer (score 5683, accepted):

The code formatting is available in Visual Studio Code through the following shortcuts:

- On Windows <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- On Mac <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- On Linux <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

Alternatively, you can find the shortcut, as well as other shortcuts, through the submenu `View / Command Palette`, also provided in the editor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>P</kbd> (or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on Mac), and then searching for ***format document**.*

## For unsaved snippets

1. Open command palette (Win: <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)
2. Find "Change Language Mode"
3. Select language e.g. `json`. By now syntax should be highlighted.
4. Format document (e.g. Open Command Palette -> "*Format Document*")

## Unformat

1. Select text
2. Command Palette -> Join Lines

## '*Show the pics*'

[image]
[image]

Comment: Also note that the code Language has to be correct. ie Format Code won't be available if plain text is selected but switching to JSON (for example) will format the selected text happily. (as happy as a text editor can be anyway)

Comment: @JoSmo:  On Ubuntu, I opened File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.  There is an item for { "key": "ctrl+shift+i", "command": "editor.action.format", "when": "editorTextFocus" }.  The command "ctrl+shift+i" works for me.

Comment: Also, apparently the file has to be saved to disk first. I had a chunk of HTML+Javascript where it couldn't format the JS, so I pasted it to a temporary window and set the language, but this didn't help either until it was saved.

Comment: For the people saying it doesn't work on a Mac, this looks like a conflict between the shortcut and the OS X text input system for accented characters which depends on your configured locale and keyboard settings:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8914#issuecomment-245947844

Comment: In current version of VSCode (1.8.1) there's action in Command + P menu "Format document" and it's available also in context menu on file contents - but only for supported types of documents.

Comment: I am trying VSCode right now, it is very slow to format the codes in my project, around 6 seconds. I don't know what's wrong here. The file that i am trying to format is around 4k lines. If i am using PHPStorm IDE, the format happens instantly.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on VS Code latest version and win 10 does this assume having a certain extension installed?

Comment: Useful for me as a beginner to VSCode. Command + P is not working in VS 1.19.3 on Mac OS X 10.13.3. But Command + Shift + P - Format Document is working fine. Also Shift + Opt + F works fine.

Comment: `Shift` + `Alt` + `F` is messing up with `'`. After pressing this combination, the `'` are changed to `"`, which is causing error in typescript.

Comment: Nope for me on 1.34.0 with a piece of hcl and the Terraform plugin installed.  I love my vi.

Comment: It used to work pretty well but now VSCode says "There is no formatter for 'plaintext'-files installed"

Comment: Note that VS Code will not allow you to format large files but instead of telling you that will just offer the generic message "no formatter installed"

Comment: If you want to change the default formatter you can do it like this: Open a file -> Right click on the code window -> Select `Format Document With...` -> `Configure Default Formatter...` -> Pick a new formatter.

Comment: I noticed when you bring out the command search, there are "Format Document" and "Reindent Lines" and "Format Document" reindent better (if in my source code, I commented out `setTimeout(function() {`  and the `}, 1000);` a few lines below, then "Reindent Lines" treat this comment as really opening up a block scope, but then also did not close the commented out closing `}`

Comment: For Mac, shift + option + F is search menu. This is not correct, at least for Mac.

Comment: Does not work with JSON unless the file has a ```.json``` extension.

Comment: Can you ***add*** something to your answer about the conditions under which this works? For instance, it does *not* work (nothing happens) by default for C# (.cs) - tried on Linux (Ubuntu MATE 20.04 with Visual Studio Code 1.41.1, 2020-05-14). Whereas it worked for an HTML (.html) file on the same system.

Comment: Possible solution for C# in: *[Visual Studio Code doesn't format C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352611/visual-studio-code-doesnt-format-c-sharp-code/47352891#47352891)*

Comment: As this is the accepted answer to a locked question that is effectively a canonical question (many people looking for formatting C#, PHP, CSS, and other languages in Visual Studio Code will end up here), it deserves a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: Under help, there is keyboard shortcut reference which points to a website with the shortcuts including this one.

Comment: @BrandonClapp How can I apply a formatter to a file that is not necessarily meant for that formatter? I am learning how to program in `Q#` in VS Code, and when I press `shift+alt+f` and look to install a `Q#` formatter, there is none found. So, I installed `Csharpier` to try and format my `Q#` scripts like `C#` scripts, but I cannot get it to apply the formatting. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Bumping this, as none of the solutions here are able to reformat C# code, to not put `{` on a new line. Any ideas what extensions are able to do this, since there are none found in the default/recommended C# extension?

Comment: helpful answer for web developers since they have lots of <div>, lolz

Answer (score 556):

**Code Formatting Shortcut:**

Visual Studio Code on Windows - <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Visual Studio Code on MacOS   - <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

You can also customize this shortcut using a preference setting if needed.

**Code Formatting While Saving the File:**

Visual Studio Code allows the user to customize the default settings.

If you want to auto format your content while saving, add the below code snippet in the work space settings of Visual Studio Code.

Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Workspace Settings*

```
{
    // Controls if the editor should automatically format the line after typing
    "beautify.onSave": true,

    "editor.formatOnSave": true,

    // You can auto format any files based on the file extensions type.
    "beautify.JSfiles": [
        "js",
        "json",
        "jsbeautifyrc",
        "jshintrc",
        "ts"
    ]
}
```

Note: now you can auto format TypeScript files. Check my update.

Comment: Also works for another language with this: [Beautify Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify)

Comment: not sure why it's different in CentOS, but it's `Shift + Alt + I`

Comment: beautify.onSave is not valid with the eslint extention installed

Comment: On ubuntu mate 17.04 it `Shift + Alt + I` too

Comment: @ClintEeastwood try using `prettier.singleQuote: true` in your vs code settings.

Comment: for Mac should be `Shift + Option + F`

Comment: Oddly this feature appears to only function with explicit saves.  In other words, auto save feature does not also trigger beautification.

Comment: Can't find 'Workplace Settings', just 'File' > 'Preferences' > 'Settings'.

Comment: @TolaOdejayi If you are using Mac OS  go to Code --> Preference --> Settings --> Workspace Settings ( Tab Navigation)

Comment: I don't see `Preference --> Settings --> Workspace Settings` in Windows ?

Comment: @shaijut it is located at `File --> Preference --> Settings` and then under the search bar you see `User` then to the right it says `Workspace`

Comment: How can I apply a formatter to a file that is not necessarily meant for that formatter? I am learning how to program in `Q#` in VS Code, and when I press `shift+alt+f` and look to install a `Q#` formatter, there is none found. So, I installed `Csharpier` to try and format my `Q#` scripts like `C#` scripts, but I cannot get it to apply the formatting. Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 242):

1. Right click somewhere in the content area (text) for the file
2. Select *Format Document* from the menu:

   - Windows: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
   - Linux: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
   - macOS: <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

Comment: For Linux the keyboard shortcuts are Ctlr + Shift + I

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful when my default formater is linked to a wrong one. You will saw an extra option "Format document with ..."

Answer (score 233):

You can add a keybinding in menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Keyboard* shortcuts.

```json
{ "key": "cmd+k cmd+d", "command": "editor.action.formatDocument" }
```

Or **Visual Studio** like:

```json
{ "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+d", "command": "editor.action.formatDocument" }
```

Comment: In Windows, replace `cmd` with `ctrl` - don't just blindly copy and paste like I did!

Comment: "editor.action.format" is working again. It now formats the whole document if nothing is selected, else formats the selection.

Answer (score 125):

The right key combination is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: When you just **copy&paste** code from clipboard to a **new tab**, then nothing happens.
Solution: **Save** the code to a file with a related **file extension** (e.g. *.json). Then it works.
I suppose the reason is that the beautifyer knows the language from the extension and doesn't do an autodetect based on the code.

Comment: This shortcut works for MAC. In Windows it formats the code.

Comment: Shortcut keys are different for different operating systems, For Linux its `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `I`

Answer (score 83):

Visual Studio Code **1.6.1** supports "*Format On Save*" which will automatically pick up relevant installed formatter extensions and format the whole document on each save.

Enable "Format On Save" by setting

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true
```

And there are available keyboard shortcuts (Visual Studio Code **1.7** and above):

**Format the whole document**: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

**Format Selection only**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Comment: I suggest EsLint extension for VS Code https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

Comment: How can this be coupled with autosave? If I make an edit, then it has to be autosaved and autoformatted. I am not able to figure out how to do this is on VS code.

Answer (score 70):

On Linux it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

On Windows it is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. Tested with HTML/CSS/JavaScript and Visual Studio Code 1.18.0.

For other languages, you might need to install a specific language package.

Answer (score 66):

For Fedora

1. Click `File` -> `Preferences` -> `Keyboard shortcuts`.
2. Under `Default Keyboard Shortcuts`, search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) for `editor.action.format`.

Mine read `"key": "ctrl+shift+i"`

You can change it as well. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29988116) on how to... or if you are feeling a little lazy to scroll up:

---

> You can add a keybinding in "Preferences->Keyboard shortcuts"
>
> `{ "key": "cmd+k cmd+d", "command": "editor.action.format" }`
>
> Or Visual Studio like:
>
> `{ "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+d", "command": "editor.action.format" }`

---

Please note: <kbd>cmd</kbd> key is only for Macs. For Windows and Fedora (Windows keyboard) use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

---

**EDIT**:

As per Visual Code version `1.28.2` this is what I found.

`editor.action.format` no longer exists. It has now been replaced by `editor.action.formatDocument` and `editor.action.formatSelection`.

Type `editor.action.format` in the search box to view existing shortcuts.

To change the key combinations follow these steps:

1. Click `editor.action.formatDocument` or `editor.action.formatSelection`
2. A pen like icon appears to the left - click it.
3. A pop-up appears. Press the desired key combination and press enter.

Comment: With this command,in my TypeScript files, single quote becomes double quote.
How to solve that?

Comment: Can't seem to locate this in the new settings garbage UI.

Comment: @DioBrando, you might want to check the TypeScript formatting extension you use.

Answer (score 48):

On Ubuntu it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

Comment: I guess it depends on the language.  `CTRL + SHIFT + I` works for JavaScript but not for PHP, for example.

Answer (score 45):

Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings*

```
"editor.formatOnType": true
```

When you enter the semicolon, it's going to be formatted.

Alternatively, you can also use `"editor.formatOnSave": true`.

Comment: oddly enough, i have found the behavior of this setting can be different than `shift+alt+f` in certain situations. don't know why though!

Comment: When I have this enable and I create a function in C#, I can complete the whole thing and move on yet the function isn't formatted until I do the "Format Document" feature. I don't know why the above setting doesn't format after typing a function.

Answer (score 37):

Just right-click on the text and select "Format code".

Visual Studio Code uses `js-beautify` internally, but it lacks the ability to modify the style you wish to use. The extension "beautify" lets you add settings.

Comment: Sure, I am using Windows and it works as described - it might depend on VScode version (please update!) and on file extension. Please test with HTML.

Comment: This is the extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify

Answer (score 28):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> does the job just fine in 1.17.2 and above.

Answer (score 26):

For some reason <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> didn't work for me on Mac Visual Studio Code 1.3.1, and actually the command "Format Document" don't worked at all. But command *Formatter* worked very well.

So you can use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and type *Formatter* or make your own shortcut in menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Keyboard Shortcuts* → <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> then type *Formatter* and add your shortcut.

See an example:

[image]

Answer (score 26):

Formatting code in Visual Studio.

I have tried to format in Windows 8.

Just follow the screenshots below.

1. Click on View on the top menu bar, and then click on Command Palette.

   [image]
2. Then a textbox would appear where we need type *Format*

   <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

   [image]

Comment: Some times I copy paste xml into a new file and want to format it without saving the file. This is perfect for such situations!

Answer (score 24):

In Visual Studio Code, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is doing what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is doing in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 23):

The simplest way I use in Visual Studio Code (Ubuntu) is:

Select the text which you want to format with the mouse.

Right click and choose *"Format selection"*.

Comment: "Format selection" doesn't exist as option

Comment: @MartijnHiemstra I am using MAC , this option is there too . Which OS you are using ?

Answer (score 21):

On Mac, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> works for me.

You can always check the key bindings in the menu:

Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Keyboard Shortcuts* and filter by keyword 'format'.

Comment: On my M1 Mac, I don't see an `alt` key

Answer (score 19):

The format shortcut in C# didn't work for me until I installed [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29) for Mac OS X, [DNVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30131118/what-is-the-dnvm/30143342#30143342) and [DNX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30131118/what-is-the-dnvm/30143342#30143342).

Before I installed Mono, the auto-format shortcut (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) worked only for the `.json` files.

Comment: In order to format C# one needs to install extensions. Normally omnisharp should work. However, there is a bug in omnisharp. Until the bug fixed we have to use Leopotam.csharpfixformat extension. It overrides omnisharp. After installing C# FixFormat extension I can format documents again.

Answer (score 16):

While changing the default behavior for Visual Studio Code requires an extension, you may override the default behavior in the workspace or user level. It works for most of the supported languages (I can guarantee HTML, JavaScript, and C#).

### Workspace level

**Benefits**

- Does not require an extension
- Can be shared among teams

**Outcomes**

- `.vscode/settings.json` is created in the project root folder

**How To?**

1. Go to: Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Workspace Settings*
2. Add and save `"editor.formatOnType": true` to settings.json (which overrides default behavior for the project you work on by creating .vscode/settings.json file).

   [image: How it looks]

### User environment level

**Benefits**

- Does not requires extension
- Personal development environment tweeking to rule them all (settings:))

**Outcomes**

- User's `settings.json` is modified (see location by operating system below)

**How To?**

1. Go to: menu *File* → *Preferences* → *User Settings*
2. Add or change the value of `"editor.formatOnType": false` to `"editor.formatOnType": true` in the user settings.json

Your Visual Studio Code user's `settings.json` location is:

Settings file locations depending on your platform, the user settings file is located here:

- Windows: `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`
- Mac: `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`
- Linux: `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json` The workspace setting file is located under the .vscode folder in your project.

More details may be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userandworkspace#_creating-user-and-workspace-settings).

Comment: But what is the consequence? How will it ***actually work*** after the change? Will it immediately / automatically change the formatting as something is typed? Also at paste?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Simply try it out and comment the answer

Answer (score 10):

By default, this key was not working for me on HTML, CSS, and JavaScript documents.

After searching, I found the popular plugin [JS-CSS-HTML Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter) with **133,796 installs**.

After installation, just reload the windows and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + 
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, and it works!

Comment: Yeah, but only 2 out of 5 stars? Seriously?

Comment: Just a reminder: this answer was originally written in 2017 and that time VS Code functionality was pretty much functional via plugins or other hacks, none of other solutions worked for me that time so I discover it by myself which actually worked that time and did not cared how many stars it have :-) Now 2020 and formatting support is fantastic out of the box.

Comment: I don't think VS Code yet supports formatting CSS out of the box. I installed the *Prettier* plugin (https://prettier.io/) which handles JavaScript, TypeScript, Flow, JSX, JSON, CSS, SCSS, Less, HTML, Vue, Angular, GraphQL, Markdown, YAML. 5.6 million installs and 4 stars.

Comment: I am glad that you found prettier :P Formatting support is there but not good as prettier, I use prettier as dev-dependency in my all projects with `.prettierrc` and plugin. I am afraid that one day prettier will merge into vs-code :)

Answer (score 10):

Select the text, right click on the selection, and select the option "command palette":

[image]

A new window opens. Search for "format" and select the option which has formatting as per the requirement.

Answer (score 9):

Just install [Visual Studio Keymap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vs-keybindings) (Visual Studio Keymap for Visual Studio Code) by Microsoft. Problem Solved. :p

Answer (score 8):

You have to install the appropriate plug-in first (i.e., XML, C#, etc.).

Formatting won't become available until you've installed the relevant plugin, and saved the file with an appropriate extension.

Comment: Beautify asks you if it doesn't know which formatter to use, allowing one to style cshtml.

Comment: As this is the only answer that addresses the question many people looking for formatting C#, PHP, CSS, and other languages in Visual Studio Code have, it deserves more comprehensive content. (The question they have is: ***"Why doesn't this work???? All the answers here claim it does!"***)

Comment: I think the content should be in this answer (as an answer to a (locked) canonical question), but a possible solution for C# is in *[Visual Studio Code doesn't format C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352611/visual-studio-code-doesnt-format-c-sharp-code/47352891#47352891)*

Answer (score 7):

For those that want to customize what JavaScript files to format, you can use the *any* extension on the `JSfiles` property. The same applies to HTML.

```json
{
    "beautify.onSave": true,
    "beautify.JSfiles": ["js", "json", "jsbeautifyrc", "jshintrc", "ts"],
    "beautify.HTMLfiles": ["htm", "html"]
}
```

This will enable beautify on save for TypeScript, and you can add in XML to the HTML option.

Comment: Where do I put this? It also helps to add that beautify is an extension...

Comment: You **could** have mentioned where to put this code.

Comment: @gromit190 You should put it in the `settings.json`. Open the Command Palette (Windows: `Ctrl+Shift+P`. Mac: `Cmd+Shift+P`), and then enter `'Open Settings (JSON)'`.

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio Code on Linux:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> to unindent block of code and

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> to make a mass indentation

Answer (score 7):

In Mac, use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and then <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: Works! But before doing this, I changed the language to `JSON` from `Plain Text`  using the status bar in the bottom right-hand corner.

Answer (score 6):

Not this one. Use this:

Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Workspace Settings*,
  *"editor.formatOnType"*: *true*

Comment: Not this one what? Are you referring to another answer? If yes, which one?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to custom the style of format-document, you should use **Beautify** extention.

Refer to this screenshot:

[image: img]

Answer (score 1):

Use extension...

Enables auto formatting of the code when you save a file.

Launch Visual Studio Code and *Quick Open* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>), paste the following command, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

> ext install format-on-save

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gyuha.format-on-save

Comment: link is dead- extension 404?