# Code formatting in Visual Studio Code is not working on C# code

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

This question already has an answer here: *[How do you format code in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357)*

All the answers provided in this question are not working with **C#** code.

I just copied my controller file and opened it in Visual Studio Code. I tried to format code with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (both right and left shifts in windows)

But it didn't work.

Is there a solution for this?

The same shortcut is working for HTML and JavaScript files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For C# you need to

- Open a folder (not a file) that contains at least one `.sln` file
- In the bottom bar you will see a blinking flame. Wait until it stops blinking.
- Click on the flame. You are going to be asked to select a file.
- In case you selected a `.sln` file click again on the flame and select a `.csproj` file.
- You can now format all `.cs` files which are part of the selected project using `Shift + Alt + F`.

Comment: I see `Assembly-*.csproj` files in the sidebar, but nothing is available besides my project `.sln` when I click the flame. Any ideas?

Comment: Just so I don't repeat this question for no good reason: Auto formatting doesn't work on c#-code that doesn't belong to a .csproj file that belongs to a .sln file?

Come from Java and thought I could just create a compilable helloworld.cs-file in a folder, compile and run it. I completely stopped working when I realized the vscode autoindentation wasn't working, woudn't have imagined that it was because it didn't belong to a project/solution structure.

Comment: Re "Shift + Alt + F": [Only in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode/29973358#29973358)?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was related with the code formatting extension.

I was using C# for "Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp)" (*ms-vscode.csharp*) extension for formatting. However, after a while the "format document" context menu has gone missing. And the key combination for formatting "Shift+Alt+F" stopped working.

After some research I have found that there is a new extension called "C# FixFormat" (*Leopotam.csharpfixformat*) for formatting C# documents which says in their description: "*there is bug in omnisharp and they are fixing the issue temporarily*".

After installing "**C# FixFormat**" extension I can now format documents again.

Comment: I will also add that "Visual Studio Code Format" extension conflicted with "C# FixFormat", and once "Visual Studio Code Format" was disabled, it worked for me.