# How to format code in Visual Studio Code on Windows

Tags: code-formatting, visual-studio-code

How can I format code in **Visual Studio Code** in the last update on Windows.

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> doesn't work...

I also tried <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. It didn't work either.

I tried the following solution, but that is not the issue:

*[How do you format code in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357)*

Comment: I am not on a windows machine right now so I am not 100%. However, you can always find out yourself, Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts, search for editor.action.format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you format code in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode)

Comment: @Harry: No, not really. That question (and its answers) has ***unstated assumptions***. Something like *"only for JavaScript, HTML, and JSON"* (the default supported). Whereas this question has unstated assumptions as well, I think. Something like *"for PHP code"* (or *"for C# code"*. Or *"for C++ code"*).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you are working on PHP you should download the PHP extension format code.

Press <kbd>F1</kbd> and type:

```
ext install PHP Code Format
```

Then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> will work.

Comment: Can you provide the *exact name* of the extension (as the provided words are not specific enough for search)? Even better would be a link to it.

Answer (score 11):

You can also select the code you want to format and **right click**, find the **format code** menu item and it should have the keyboard command listed next to it.

By default it should be <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>**/**<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: You talk about Visual Studio Code because i can't find what you say ?

Comment: the shortcut worked for me ( Shift + Alt + F ). They should add it under Edit or somthing.

Answer (score 7):

Simply use **Ctrl + Shift + I**
Or
*Right Click* on document and *Click* on **Format Document**

Answer (score 7):

If it's for **JavaScript, JSON, CSS, [Sass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29), and HTML**, there no better way than the **Beautify extension**. It is simple and very useful!

Once installed the way you do it are described here with good illustrations (to avoid content duplication):
*[How can I format PHP files with HTML markup in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330707/how-to-format-php-files-with-html-markup-in-visual-studio-code/46855721#46855721)*

**For others languages**, you add the **appropriate extensions** and you can **set keybinding** (you need to get the appropriate command to execute, and add the keybinding to **keybindings.json**). **I have explained that in the link above**. Always **read well the documentation** of the **extensions**. There you can **find all the possible configurations** and so.

**For specific languages** you can **search via Visual Studio Code** in the **extension marketplace**. Enter just **Beautify** and you will see all the different Beautify extensions for the different languages. Also you can **use** **formatting format formatter** **keywords**, like PHP formatting and so.

Also, you can use the **integrated formatting tool of Visual Studio Code**. Mostly by **clicking right and selecting formatting document**, you can also format just a selection.

Here is the shortcut for formatting the whole document:

- On Windows: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- On Mac: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- On Ubuntu: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

As `abdullam` mentioned in his comment, the shortcut that worked for me is
*Shift + Alt + F*.

(The accepted answer didn't work for me. I am using Visual Studio Code on a Mac. I couldn't find the extension mentioned above i.e *ext install PHP Code Format*.)

Answer (score 0):

Formatting any document in Visual Studio Code requires one to install a formatter plugin, like **Prettier - Code formatted** by *Esben Petersen*.

- Install the plugin: **[Prettier - Code formatter](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode.git)** from the *Extensions* window in Visual Studio Code.

  - You can open the extensions window from the left aligned sidebar or simply by pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>X</kbd>
- Post installation, from the required page you can try the below

  - Right click and choose *Format Document*;
    ***or***
  - Try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on Windows

The document should now be properly formatted.

> - PS:  You can set *"Prettier - Code formatted"* as the default formatter for Visual Studio Code  by performing the following:
>
>   - Open *Settings* by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> and search for `editor.defaultFormatter`. Choose `esbenp.prettier-vscode` from the list and Save.
>       By default, now formatting any document with the above steps will use *Prettier* as the default formatter.