# How could configure vscode 4 letters as indentations

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running vscode on ubuntu

[image]

but find its indentation of 4 spaces is actually takes two letters spaces.

It looks very compact.

How could configure it to take 4 letters as indentations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indentation in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44995219/indentation-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

Everything is configured finely but indentation is squeezed.

It's ridiculous,

I finally solved the problem by edit the fonts in setting.json

```
{
        "editor.fontFamily": "'Monaco', 'monospace',monospace",

    }
```