# Why does it says: 'Klasa' object has no attribute 'ispisi? When ispisi is method that I am trying to call

Tags: python, oop, calculator

```
class Klasa:
   def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

    def oduzmi(self,x,y):
        return  x - y

    def ispisi(self):
        print('rezultat je: ', self.oduzmi(self.x,self.y))

klasa = Klasa(2,3)
klasa.ispisi()
```

Comment: Is that the indentation you are using? It looks like `ispisi` is inside the constructor.

Comment: It looks like. I moved left( removed indentation), but its giving me the same result. Nothing changes

Comment: With corrected indentation I get output: https://ideone.com/kSwMwk

Comment: @JohnnyMopp , you were right it was indentation mistake. Thank you! :)

Comment: Indentation errors are much easier to spot (and harder to make in the first place) if you consistently use 4 spaces for each level.

Comment: I am always using tab? Is that ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the indentations please if you are using vscode i suggest you to check [Indentation in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44995219/indentation-in-vs-code)

```
class Klasa:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def oduzmi(self,x,y):
        return  x - y

    def ispisi(self):
        print('rezultat je: ', self.oduzmi(self.x,self.y))

klasa = Klasa(2,3)
klasa.ispisi()
```