# Visual studio code + format code command

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting

In referencence to this question

[How do you format code in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode/38249134)

`Shift + alt + f` (to reformating code) work fine

But i have a problem :

Can we keep carriage return (or new line) in memory ?

because if i do (for more lisibility) :

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" 
        class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Enter a name">
    </div>
</form>
```

If I use reformating code command, it came back to the start, all inline.

How can this be avoided ?

Comment: No body have a tips ?