# how to get vs code `ENTER` to respect/cleanup whitespace

Tags: visual-studio-code

BTW, this is not asking how to format code in VS, or the keybinding, so please don't mark it duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode). It is specifically about formatting during typing.

Given the following code:

```
if(true) {
    console.log('hello');
    console.log('world');
}
```

If I go to the end of the 'log hello' line, hit `DEL` to bring 'log world' to the end of the line I will get (with | representing my cursor):

```
if(true) {
    console.log('hello');|        console.log('world');
}
```

Now, if I hit `ENTER`, I will get:

```
if(true) {
    console.log('hello');
    |        console.log('world');
}
```

In other editors I would expect the white space to be 'eaten up' and the line to be reformatted, looking like this again:

```
if(true) {
    console.log('hello');
    |console.log('world');
}
```

Any thoughts on how to change this behavior?

This would also (hopefully) handle the pasting in of code that was not properly formatted, for instance, if I wanted to paste the following in:

```
                console.log('arrrgg');
            console.log('matey');
```

To the end of the if, I would see:

```
if(true) {
    console.log('hello');
    console.log('world');
                        console.log('arrrgg');
            console.log('matey');
}
```

Instead of:

```
if(true) {
    console.log('hello');
    console.log('world');
    console.log('arrrgg');
    console.log('matey');
}
```

Certainly, I can hit `Shift-Alt-F` and reformat, but I don't always want to reformat an entire file....

I think I have been spoiled with VS and WebStorm automatically cleaning up and reformatting code quickly. Not sure if that is a valid

Is this even possible in Code?

Comment: I cannot recreate this issue. Perhaps move this to a Github issue and we can ask more team members to get involved.

Comment: Thanks Wade, will do.