# Visual Studio Code Does Not Format .cs files

Tags: visual-studio-code

couple of weeks ago I installed Visual Studio Code on my Windows machine. It is lightweight and I love it. But there is one problem that drives me crazy. The program cannot format .cs files. If I open .Net Core project, there is no problem on formatting. I changed the language from bottom right to C# and saved the file locally still no success. Is there any way to format code in single .cs file? I know there is already an asked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode) for this problem but the solutions does not apply if there is no project created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command pallet (crtl-shift-P), type "format" and select "format code". Assuming the extension for the current language supports that.

TypeScript does, but [C#](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp) does not.

You could raise an [issue](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues) (if one does not already exist).

Comment: Oops... will update. Appears this is a per-language operation and the C# extension doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have been wondering about this one.