# Why is VSCode not showing formatting commands?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just installed VSCode and am trying to format a C# file.  However none of the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29973358/782880) work.  When I use the search functionality provided via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>P</kbd> and then searching for ***format code***., nothing comes up.

I've tried this for many different file types, and formatting never is an option.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Formatting for C# is provided by the [Omnisharp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp) extension. Have you installed it ?

Comment: yes, it's installed.  Is there a "format code" command?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the C# extension installed, make sure that there is a `project.json` with minimal content in the root directory of your project.

[image]

There does need to be minimal content in the project.json file. Here an example of minimal content for the project.json file:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": { }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, that *does* show the command now, but it does nothing.  What goes inside the JSON?  So if you open individual files, you are out of luck with formatting?

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit The JSON contains the .NET Core project configuration. I've added an example. I do not now know how to use C# formatting commands without a project.json file in the workspace root.