# How to Use AMP in Asp.net MVC

Tags: amp-html

I want to use Accelerated Mobile Page in MVC project 
I am working in asp.net MVC project in that I have two file one for mobile and one for desktop  . so can I  use AMP for mobile?
anything problem arise if I can use combine?
or I have to create new project for mobile?

Answer (score 3):

This is the easiest way to use Amp in your Asp.net Mvc application.

**Step #1 Controller**

Create a controller name it **AMP** like

```
 public class AmpController : Controller
{

 public ActionResult Index()
    {
      //Return page which contain Amp
     return View();

    } 
}
```

Add this line before returning view to your existing Home or default controller which will redirect mobile traffic to **Amp**

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
        if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
          {
           Response.Redirect("~/Amp/Index");          
          }
         //This is not Amp View
            return View();
      }
  }
```

**Step #2**
**Index View**

The view of Amp controller's index file must be **Amp** validated ,you can check whether the page html render is Amp or not by starting your asp.net mvc project and browse **localhost:0000/Amp/Index** here replace with your own localhost ,
then when page is shown right click view source copy it then past to [Amp validator](https://validator.ampproject.org/) to check if it is valid.

Here is valid Amp html which you can past inside Index of Amp controller view
go to [Amp site](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/getting_started/create/basic_markup)

In this way you can create Amp pages in Asp.net mvc.

**Addition**

Do not forget to replace these [Razor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c) attribute when using **Amp**

1. Form **action** attribute replace with **action-xhr**
   see [Here](https://www.ampproject.org/fr/docs/reference/components/amp-form)
2. Css can be use only inside **Here** see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199925/external-style-sheet-is-not-valid-in-amp-pages)
3. Javascript can be written using amp-iframe first you need to write this line to use amp-iframe inside **head**

Then you can use javascript like this inside **body**

```
<amp-iframe width="0" height="0"
              sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"
              layout="responsive"
              frameborder="0"
              src="~/Scripts/yourscriptname.js">
  </amp-iframe>
```

4.**White Spaces Matters** when using Amp ,if you leave spaces or anything when writing Amp html you may face validation errors so you need to format your code using [Vs Format code] or [css compressor](https://csscompressor.com/)[7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode),idea behind this is your page consume more bytes when it has more white space.When you copy and paste Amp code from their site on notepad or any editor it will add some extra spaces in code so that that page will not be validate as amp.

5.**Available on Git**
[Here](https://github.com/malwareoverflow/AmpInMvc) is my Amp project on Mvc,but you can modify it according to your business needs if you are working with SEO.

Comment: Point 4 isn't correct. Whitespace isn't a problem in a valid AMP page - the AMP content we output is formatted and we have had no problems. I'd also question why you need JS and AMP is supposed to be lightweight. If the JS is for visual purposes I'd have a look at the changes to the spec as functionality is being added all the time. However if you must include JS the caveat is that it should be placed in an iframe (as pointed out above) at least 600px from the top of the page.

Comment: no I mean to say when you copy and paste Amp code from their site on notepad or any editor it will add some extra spaces in code so that that page will  not be validate as amp I have tried this ,you too can check).

Answer (score 2):

It might be a good idea to read the [AMP Project](https://www.ampproject.org/) website. However we have ASP.NET WebForms and we have dynamically created AMP versions of our content by stripping out the HTML and converting the content to support AMP tags. In other words we have two versions of the code, one AMP one non AMP.

In your particular case you'll have to write code which takes your existing code base and outputs an AMP version.

My advice - Google, read, and repeat.

Comment: Your solution has the overhead to reprocess the html as a drawback and also you have a little control over the generated AMP code.

Comment: For the solution we have I'm taking the content from the database and manipulating it on the fly when rendering the AMP page. This was needed because the content we have is dated and has only unsupported HTML tags. I'm not lucky enough to have clean perfect W3C compliant code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to create a new project since the main difference between AMP and non-AMP versions is just your views and you probably should not have to touch on your controllers or models.

There is an [interesting article](https://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/creating-google-amp-pages-with-aspnet-mvc-E7) that has a clean solution by registering a custom display mode that dynamically decides if the asp.net mvc have to serve the AMP or non-AMP version.

Comment: I don't think that's the best solution. As you'll note the author points out simply adding a few things to make an AMP version of the content didn't work and resulted in errors. Might be better to read his follow up [post](https://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/google-amp-aftermath-replacing-images-using-actionfilters-EI).

To create an AMP version of the page you will essentially have to manipulate the content before outputting it to the browser.

Comment: I did it in two projects and I'm sure that it works perfecly and I it gives me much more control over the AMP-Html than if I was using an action filter to intecerpt the generated html (overhead). I sincerely hope you didn't downvote my answer just based on your preference by your own solution (overhead is something that I do not like but I won't downvote your answer just because I disagree with your point of view)

Comment: The downvote was given because the link isn't useful. The update in the article might have been but no the answer isn't helpful. Nothing personal.