# How to use Google AMP with ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, amp-html

I'm trying to use `Google AMP` with `Asp.Net`.

The only code I have is,

```
<script async custom-element="amp-iframe" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-iframe-0.1.js"></script>
<amp-iframe width="200" height="100"
  sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"
  layout="responsive"
  frameborder="0"
  src="https://www.example.com/htmlfile.html">
</amp-iframe>
```

Can anyone help me with the code ?
Thanks

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: @Alex I don't know how to implement it. There should write amp on the browser address bar, but its not.

Comment: Have you checked this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743152/how-to-use-amp-in-asp-net-mvc)? If you're looking for Google AMP using ASP.Net MVC, you can try the solution offered from that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm visiting [Amp.dev](https://Amp.dev)

This is the official resource for Google AMP as I know.