# Visual Studio Code remove all tabs when formating C# code

Tags: c#, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.9.0 on Kubuntu and have issues when formatting code manually. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29973358/3276634) I learned, that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> is the shortcut for code formatting. But it doesn't format the code well, instead it's more uglified!

As an example, I have the following C# model saved in a .cs file

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class TimetableSubject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public TimetableSubject(int? id = null, string name = "")
        {
            Name = name;
            Id = id.HasValue ? id.Value : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I press the keyboard shortcut and my code is a real mess:

```
namespace MyApp {
public class TimetableSubject {
public int Id {get; set; }
public string Name {get; set; }

public TimetableSubject(int?id = null, string name = "") {
Name = name; 
Id = id.HasValue?id.Value:0; 
}
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I want clean format according to the C# conventions, like Visual Studio does on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut. I already installed the official C# extension called `ms-vscode.csharp`. This gave me VS features like showing the usage of methods/fields, but no working formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, enter *>Format*, choose *Formatter*. Now `formatter.json` file opens, which contains rules, how Visual Studio Code would format code. Here you can append own rules for C# files like this:

```
"cs": {
     "indent_size": 4,
      "indent_char": " ",
}
```