# How to shift several codes lines at once in Visual Code

Tags: ide

when I am writing the codes I like to order it well to be well designed,

I need to know what is the command in Visual code(IDE from Microsoft) to move the multi-code lines to the right or left!  and s there an extension gives VC the nice preview sidebar like sublime text?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you format code in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode)

Comment: For me the question is about moving not formatting - you can move the code left/right using TAB/SHIFT+TAB. If you have something else in mind please rephrase the question so it will be more clear.

Comment: @BrianJ useful Thanks :)