# How to easy change XAML Code style (listed to one line)

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

is there an easy and fast way to change between this XAML-Code styles inside Visual Studio XAML-Editor?
Perhaps a Key-Shortcut?

Between listed:

```
<ContentControl Width="130"
                MinWidth="50"
                Height="130"
                MinHeight="50"
                Canvas.Top="150"
                Canvas.Left="470"
                Template="{StaticResource DesignItemTemplate}">
```

and one line:

```
    <ContentControl Width="130" MinWidth="50" Height="130" MinHeight="50" Canvas.Top="150" Canvas.Left="470" Template="{StaticResource DesignItemTemplate}">
```

Comment: Not know of this kind of shortcut. Perhaps you can check [Xaml Formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145296/how-to-automatically-format-xaml-code-in-visual-studio).

Comment: This option is available in Visual Studio under options->Text Options->Xaml somewhere and the current code style is called 'smart'. You can change that option and then just format the document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Visual Studio 2017 go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > XAML > Formatting > Spacing, and select "Insert a single space between attributes". Then you can reformat your xaml file (Ctrl+K+D).

For VSCode you can use [XML Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabianlauer.vs-code-xml-format). It will make your xaml file to what you need by default.

Comment: Super, that is what i am looking for. But if i can change between both styles with a short-cut it will be perfect.

Comment: There is only one way that I know of! And it's a little complicated! All VisualStudio options are stored in the in %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\[VERSION]\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings file. This is actually a XML file. What you need to change is placed in `<Category name="XAML_Spacing"...> <PropertyValue name="AttributeFormat">[HERE]`. Create two Console applications which they set the value to what you need (Preserver, SingleSpace, or NewLine). Then add your applications to VisualStudio (Tools>External Tools). And finally set shortcut keys for them!

Comment: Nice Idea. I tried to change the Attribute with an editor while VS was running. But the attribute does not change. I need to restart VS.

Comment: Yeah. You're right! Sorry for that!! Check this out: [Writing to the User Settings Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/writing-to-the-user-settings-store?view=vs-2017)

Comment: @Twister sorry to revive an old thread, but did you ever manage to make a keyboard shortcut? I'm currently playing around with it myself