# Visual Studio Code doesn't format C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I created a new file, set the C# language, and wrote some code. Then I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (or <kbd>F1</kbd> → *Format Document*). And got I the error

> Sorry, but there is no formatter for 'csharp'-files installed.

Also, I installed *C# Extension*, but it didn't help.
The Visual Studio Code version is 1.18.0.

Comment: Check out this extension: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode

Comment: The canonical is *[How do you format code in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357)*, but unfortunately none of the answers address this question.

Comment: just select current project by command palette: Omnisharp > select project

Answer (score 91):

If you have [prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) as the default formatter as I do, you should do this:

1. Open your vscode settings with these shortcut: `ctrl + ,`, or [image]
2. Then click to "open settings (JSON)": [image]
3. This is where you should paste the below snippet.

This is my config:

```
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[csharp]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-dotnettools.csharp"
  }
}
```

*For you to apply this configuration you need [c#](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp) extension.*

Comment: Just curious, how did you find out the information regarding ms-dotnettools.csharp

Comment: Basically just scrolling through vscode-intellisense (suggestions), and just tried it out and worked.

Comment: Basically you tell the formatter to use `ms-dotnettools.csharp` for C# and `esbenp.prettier-vscode` for any other language. I guess prettier has no C# formatter currently. There might be plugins around...

Comment: Thank you, i was facing the same issue, prettier was trying to format it by default

Comment: If you still have an issue with indent, check the @Samuel Ridings answer bellow

Comment: you should also add the "editor.formatOnSave": true that it formats the code onsave

Comment: I was pasting some c# code from another system into a new file (without saving) and formatting wasn't working. I eventually got it working by saving the code into a file called CSharpFileForFormatting.cs and saving that in a folder. Open that folder in VS code and the formatting worked.

Comment: You have many options available to custom you formatting by creating a .editorconfig file and add options from the doc there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/code-style-rule-options?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 37):

This works for me.

*Note:* If it is `true` then clear the checkbox and set it to true again. After that, you must restart Visual Studio Code.

Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings* →

[image]

Comment: It is Shift+Alt+F on windows, Ctrl + Shift + I on ubuntu

Comment: Thank you - I use the Visual Studio extension that makes the `Format` hotkeys the same as the big brother IDE. I recommend it.

The C# FixFormat extension is _only_ for C# ~3/4/5 unity engine projects on mac

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `(requires restart)`. I totally missed it.

Comment: does not work for me, after the restart still asks me for the formatter for csharp files

Answer (score 26):

Visual Studio Code with [OmniSharp](https://www.omnisharp.net/#portfolioModal-vscode) doesn't format C# code without a .csproj file.

You can create a new project with `dotnet new console` with the .NET Core SDK.

Comment: File names also have to be TitleCased as well.

Comment: what do you mean "without", what if a open a folder, not a sln or csproj file, but the edited cs file does belong finally to a csproj

Answer (score 10):

Try to create an **OmniSharp config** for your project that will allow you to customize the formatting of C# code. 
Create the `omnisharp.json` in the project root (near the `.sln` file)

```json
{
  "FormattingOptions": {
    "newLine": "\n",
    "useTabs": false,
    "tabSize": 4,
    "indentationSize": 4
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** to confirm updates in `omnisharp.json` you should reload vscode (`ctrl`+`shift`+`p` -> `Developer: Reload Window`)

More info about OmniSharp config: https://www.strathweb.com/2017/01/c-code-formatting-settings-in-vs-code-and-omnisharp/

Comment: [Here](https://www.strathweb.com/2017/01/c-code-formatting-settings-in-vs-code-and-omnisharp/) is a good full `omnisharp.json`, example and other info.

Comment: This is by far the best and easiest solution.  Just one thought though, I edit the `omnisharp.json` file in my `%USERPROFILE%/.omnisharp/` directory so the settings are available to all my sessions, not just the current one.  You can find the official documentation [here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/wiki/Configuration-Options).

Answer (score 8):

1. Browse the Visual Studio Code extension library, and make sure you've got the C# extension installed `ms-dotnettools.csharp`

   [image: VS Code extensions pane showing C# OmniSharp extension]
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> to open the Settings panel. Change the `editor.formatOnType` setting to be enabled. This wasn't enabled by default in my Visual Studio Code.

   [image: VS Code settings window with editor.formatOnType setting]
3. Restart Visual Studio Code. It should now make code auto-format when you complete the line with a semicolon, or when you close the outer brace of a scope.

Note: this is a global setting for the editor, so it may enable auto-formatting for other languages and not just C#.

This was tested on Visual Studio Code version 1.43.1.

Comment: that was not asked by OP, to enable the format on type

Answer (score 6):

The C# extension powered by Omnisharp doesn't have a formatter included (as far as I know).

You can install [C# FixFormat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Leopotam.csharpfixformat). That does the trick for me, but the formatting is not as good as in Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: i just found it too. turns out, that this is the only option.

Comment: Omnisharp does include a C# formatter. Just make sure to open the file from withing a folder - please see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59154222/565985

Comment: @Yaniv how do you prevent formatters like prettier from interfering with OmniSharp's formatter?

Comment: It's 2020 and FixFormat is as bad as it was. I hoped I could really use VS Code to develop Blazor projects, but not really. One of the main issues is really bad formatting provided. No good plugins, Blazor and Razor files treated as they was invented yesterday. But the worst thing in FixFormat is really bad english used to describe the options. A lots of "Spaces or tabs: yes or no" kind of nonsenses. So VS Community. Still many, many bugs, but at least formatting is almost fully configurable.

Comment: This extension is now unpublished from Marketplace. 

Comment: This extension is now unpublished from Marketplace. You can choose to uninstall it.  Yeah, same message for future readers.  I'm sad I missed this one.

Answer (score 6):

I found there was another setting interfering with formatting C#.

```
"omnisharp.useEditorFormattingSettings": true
```

Setting this to `false` fixed indenting for me.

Comment: I couldn't find this particular setting, however I discovered that if chose the "Omnisharp: Select Project" followed by selecting my project then my formatting was sorted

Comment: worked for me! after trying every other solution, turned out when I switched to another project from the cmd, vscode didn't actually change the current project

Comment: This also worked for me, thank you

Answer (score 4):

It is resolved after updating to Visual Studio Code 1.20.1 and re-enabling [OmniSharp](https://www.omnisharp.net/#portfolioModal-vscode).

And just set "csharp.format.enable" to "true" in Workspace Settings (if it was true and not working yet, change it to false and then to true).

Comment: `"csharp.format.enable": true` didn't work for me, and I have to install **c# FixFormat**, but then it asked me to turn off `csharp.format.enable`, which has no effect anyway, weird.

Comment: In my case changing `tab size` params caused losing formatter and only setting `"csharp.format.enable": true` fixed it. I have only `C# (by Omnisharp)` installed.

Answer (score 3):

If you are still hitting this issue, please note that the [OmniSharp](https://www.omnisharp.net/#portfolioModal-vscode) extension will not behave nicely on .cs files that [was not opened from inside a folder](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2829) ([from here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1967#issuecomment-458358919)).

In order to workaround this - make sure you open the desired file from within a folder (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>):

[image]

Then the formatting will work (as well as other OmniSharp features).

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I have the OmniSharp extension installed and up to date, and I have opened a folder in VSCode.  I then open a .cs file by clicking on it in the left panel, but when I try to format it tells me there is no formatter installed.

Comment: What about when there's no file at all? I just open a new editor, paste some source code and I want to format it. That's what I often do with JSON data, for example, and it works without any issue. But with a C# code, it doesn't for some reason. I have the `ms-dotnettools.csharp` extension.

Comment: what do you mean "behave nicely"??

Answer (score 2):

This issue happened to me when the visual studio released new update for 2022, I resolved this by downloading the new .Net 6.0 which you will find https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0
in this link.

Answer (score 2):

I solved that issue by simply pressing F1, writing "format", and hitting enter.
In my case, there was no default formatter set in my environment so it prompted me options for formatters.
I believe there was only one for C#.

Answer (score 2):

Open vscode go to output > [image: the output of vs code]

As you can see, the output is set to task. Change it to OmniSharp log and check if it says the dotnet version is not supported. If yes then update your dotnet version. Hope it helps.

Comment: It had an error saying that I was using an old version of .Net (~3.0.1), installed .Net SDK 6.0 and the error disappeared!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I previously installed both `dotnet` and `dotnet-sdk` via Homebrew and those seemed to cause a conflict of OmniSharp. So I removed `dotnet` by:

```sh
brew uninstall dotnet
```

Also, just in case, I re-installed `dotnet-sdk` by:

```sh
brew reinstall dotnet-sdk
```

Plus, I restarted my Mac, then it finally worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

**FOR MAC USERS**

I solved the issue by setting

```
"omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "never"
```

in the VS code settings, it will also prompt you to restart Omnisharp and after that it should work with the `shift + option + f` key combination

Answer (score 1):

Check the Omnisharp log to see if its giving a reason for the lack of formatting. In my case it was dotnet sdk needed updating.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I kept pressing Shift + Alt + F (Format Document), thinking my formatter is not working because it was not chaning something I though was misformatted:

```cs
namespace MyApp // Note: actual namespace depends on the project name.
{
    internal class Program
    {

        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(_clientId)
    .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, _tenantId)
    .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")
    .Build();

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

it turns out that with the default settings, the microsoft c# extension is ok with this formatting, it doesn't think there is something to fix. If I change the indentation of the first line it fixes it.

So: Your code might already be formatted!

Comment: Do you know what setting influences this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Even after setting tab/space size in VSCode Omnisharp still uses its own rules you can change them by having an "omnisharp.json" with custom rules.
for more information on these rules and where you can add the file check [this article](https://www.strathweb.com/2017/01/c-code-formatting-settings-in-vs-code-and-omnisharp/).

Answer (score 0):

Working fine in Windows:

```
--> Shift + Alt + F
```

Answer (score 0):

windows : Shift+Alt+F
ubuntu: : Ctrl + Shift + I

Answer (score 0):

my config is the following:

Inside my settings.json
I have this setting:

```
"[csharp]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-dotnettools.csharp",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

Now I have my code formated in visual studio code

```
class Person
{
    public void Saludar()
    {

    }

    public void Comer()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

Use the [Synaptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptic_(software)) package manager and mark the code package for 'Full Removal' and click apply.

Like [here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/660):

```
Delete ~/.vscode
Delete ~/.config
Reinstall
```

It worked for me.

Comment: @andoral Do what peter suggested with C# FixFormat , this will work if you're using ubuntu , sorry I didn't pay attention that you're using windows OS