# Formatting .aspx code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-code, format

I've got some legacy code I'm trying to edit in Visual Studio Code. It's a mix of HTML and C#
EG:

```
<section id="mod-minisearch">
    <!--#includefile="assets/includes/mini-search.aspx"-->
    <% Server.Execute("/something/code.aspx")
</section>
```

It's a bit like Razor, but not the same. I've tried a number of Formatters C#, Razor, HTML etc. All destroy the code in one way or another.

If I format it in Visual Studio (2019) it's great. Is there a way I can use Visual Studio's formatter in Visual Studio Code?

I know the simple answer would be, "use Visual Studio instead of Code", but there are a number of reason for using Visual Studio Code over Visual Studio.

Thanks.

Update:
I've now setup my default formatter to be
[Prettier - Code formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)

This works fine if I right click and select Format Document, but when I save it insists in putting spaces in places like this

Before save

```
Server.Execute("/Modules/
```

After save

```
Server.Execute(" /Modules/
```

Which can break the code. I've disabled format on save for the moment. But can anybody think why this would happen. This is my setup Json.

```
"editor.defaultFormatter": "mblode.pretty-formatter",
"[HTML]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "mblode.pretty-formatter",
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should take a look at this post [Visual Studio Code doesn't format C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352611/visual-studio-code-doesnt-format-c-sharp-code)

Or try using this C# FixFormat
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Leopotam.csharpfixformat