# Indentation in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, auto-indent

I know that I can format code in VSC by doing as in this link:
[How do you format code in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode)

However, I want only the indentation and not other formatting. For example, I don't want the first `{` of the for-loop to end up on the row below the `for`. How do I do that?

Once again. When highlighting and formatting this piece of code:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("hello\n");
}
```

I do NOT want this result:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("hello\n");
}
```

But I DO want this result:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("hello\n");
}
```

Comment: You can install the Clang-format plugin for VSCode and configure it.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+k,Ctrl+f gives exactly the indent type you want. This works in java as far as I have tried.