# Change positioning of {} with auto-format in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I auto-format my code in VS Code it formats to:

```
void funtion()
{
}
```

How can I change it to auto-format to this:

```
void foo() {
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT: VISUAL STUDIO CODE**

I'd like to change my answer.
I realized you were actually talking about Visual Studio **Code** later, even though you correctly specified that with your tags. My apologies.

In all fairness things are different. As per this [link](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1506), you should

> Add the following setting:

```
{
    "FormattingOptions": {
        "NewLinesForBracesInLambdaExpressionBody": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInAnonymousMethods": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInAnonymousTypes": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInControlBlocks": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInTypes": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInMethods": false,
                "NewLinesForBracesInProperties": false,
                "NewLinesForBracesInAccessors": false,
        "NewLineForElse": false,
        "NewLineForCatch": false,
        "NewLineForFinally": false
    }
}
```

> to:
>
> omnisharp.json at the root of your project (the folder which you open
>   in VS Code) - if you want to enforce this change on a specific project
>   only %USERDATA%/.omnisharp/omnisharp.json if you want to enforce this
>   globally

In my case, no such file existed.
So I went to [C:\Users\MyUserName.omnisharp](http://C:%5CUsers%5CMyUserName%5C.omnisharp) (on Windows; bear with me, I'll also write that for Mac) and created a text file, filled it with the above content and renamed it omnisharp.json

Then, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to auto-format code ([which works for Mac too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37429293/5480409)), I got

```
void foo() {
}
```

**In your case**, as per this [link](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/issues/853), **the omnisharp folder on Mac** should be at

> ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.x.x/bin/omnisharp
>
> Where 1.x.x is the version of Omnisharp/C# extension for VS Code that you have installed.

All previous steps (to get started with C# development) were [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code).

---

**VISUAL STUDIO**

I assume you are talking about C# from your syntax.
From the **Tools** menu choose **Options**, open the TreeView to the left like in the image below and then uncheck any option regarding new lines and braces, i.e. "Place open brace on new line for types" and all the others you want to change:

[image: options]

In your case, since you are talking about methods, you should uncheck "**Place open brace on new line for methods and local functions**", the second option from the top.

Since you ask about iOS, here's the Tool menu:

[image]

Comment: Where can I find the Tools menu? I'm on Mac.

Comment: top center of your window

Comment: The only options the menu bar shows are:
Code, File, Edit, Selection, View, Go, Debug, Tasks, Windows, Help

Comment: @WillTaylor I added a picture

Comment: @WillTaylor I'm sorry, I edited my post for your case, i.e. Visual Studio Code. Let me know how it turns out

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE!

OmniSharp now has a global configuration:

```
macOS/Linux: ~/.omnisharp/omnisharp.json
Windows: %APPDATA%\OmniSharp\omnisharp.json
```