# How can I modify the code formatting for C++ in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

So far after installing the C++ extension tool, I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to auto-format my C++ code. However, I would like to make some modification, for example I would like to force the pointer alignment to be near the type, instead of next to the variable name, such as this rule:

```
# Force pointers to the type for C++.
DerivePointerAlignment: false
PointerAlignment: Left
```

How can I do this modification? I've tried to create a .clang-format file, but it doesn't work.

Comment: ctrl+K+F is core VS functionality, it's unclear what tool you're talking about. I'd say, you should redirect it to other site (maybe VS tech support?)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode

Comment: I get confused between `Ctrl` + `K` +`F` (format) and `Ctrl` + `K`, `F` (close directory) all the time.

Comment: `"C_Cpp.formatting": "vcFormat"` solved this very issue to me, the pointers are placed close to the type, not close to the identifier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some experiments, the simple solution is to add this line in the User Settings (settings.json):

`"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ PointerAlignment: Left}"`

However, this settings allow me to keep my previous settings without breaking my function line:

`"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ BasedOnStyle: WebKit, ColumnLimit: 120, PointerAlignment: Left}"`

Using "BasedOnStyle: Visual Studio" such as this line:

`"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ BasedOnStyle: Visual Studio, ColumnLimit: 120, PointerAlignment: Left}"`

**doesn't work**. It is may be a bug.
I used Visual Studio Code version 1.26.1.

Additionally, a .clangformat outside the workspace folder will still be applied. So, if this file is corrupt the auto-format will not work.

Comment: It's funny that I use Chromium instead, but searched for this answer to override just those 2 settings (column limit and pointer alignment) :D

Comment: So I have {BasedOnStyle: Chromium, ColumnLimit: 150, PointerAlignment: Left}

Comment: I don't understand why anyone would want type information, such as whether something is a pointer or not, to be grouped with the identifier.
If `class Student` is a large structure, like 100,000 bytes in size, there is a big difference between a `Student` and a pointer to a `Student`, since pointers are generally 4 bytes or 8 bytes, depending on the architecture. And this is only taking into consideration the difference in size, not the fact that they are two very different things, conceptually.

Comment: @Pulseczar I actually prefer the pointer indication to be near the identifier rather than the type because, syntactically, that's how the language treats it. If  I have multiple identifiers identified with one type, `int *p, n;` declares `p` to be an `int` pointer and `n` to be an `int`. Writing it as `int* p, n;` seems visually misleading. I suppose it's subjective.

Comment: @lurker That seems like a poor reason to split up type information. I wonder why the creators of C did it that way, to begin with. Thanks for the response.

Comment: When pasting functions using this answer (`C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ BasedOnStyle: WebKit, ColumnLimit: 120, PointerAlignment: Left}`), such as copying the following with line breaks where the '\n' is (since StackOverflow doesn't allow line breaks in comments):
`void func(int& var) {\n
return;\n
}`
and pasting, VSCode seems to paste it all into one line:
`void func(int& var) { return; }`
Undoing once with "Ctrl+Z" fixes this after paste, but you must do it every time

Answer (score 4):

I use clang-format, which integrates quite well and is very configurable.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-ide#_code-formatting

Comment: Thanks Michael, actually I've read the docs. Today I found the issue. I placed a .clangformat file outside the workspace (inside my Windows user folder), which contains a wrong format in a line. After I removed it or repaired the content it works again. I thought this file should not have effect. So the VS-Code not just look after the file inside the workspace.