# Visual Studio Code on Mac doesn't format correctly

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I love a lot about Visual Studio Code.
But on my Mac it does not format coding. The way it handles indenting is very frustrating.
Some code text editors allow you to select all your code and 'tidy' or 'reformat' it to fix any bad indenting, but Visual Studio Code doesn't appear to have any options for this.
Can anyone provide any tips or solutions?

Comment: What files are you trying to format? There are extensions like prettier that will help with js files.

Comment: a few things, but what I notice it on most is standard .html files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate the menu: Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts. Search for "format".

The default for `editor.action.formatDocument` is <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

The default for `editor.action.formatSelection` is <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Here's a [similar question with answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode).