# How to remove all unused parameters/ imports, add missing imports, and do prettify via script

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

In vscode, there is option to remove unused imports, add all missing imports, and prettify (ALT + SHIFT +f).

I have files generator, and i wont to do all this stuff via code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode seems like a duplicate

Comment: no, i search way to do it via code/sript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible with my library [ts-morph](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph). Here's some sample code that does this for every file associated with a tsconfig.json:

```
import { Project } from "ts-morph";

const project = new Project({ tsConfigFilePath: "tsconfig.json" });

for (const sourceFile of project.getSourceFiles()) {
    sourceFile.fixMissingImports()
        .organizeImports()
        .fixUnusedIdentifiers()
        .formatText();
}

project.save().then(() => console.log("done"));
```

All of these methods accept arguments for specifying how formatting should be done (limited by the configurations available in the compiler API).

Comment: thanks, i already using your awesome library. but don't know that it is possible . thanks!

Comment: It is not remove my unused const data = require('.data.json');

Comment: @yantrab I updated the answer to include variable declarations.

Comment: @yantrab in ts-morph 2.0 there is a new `fixUnusedIdentifiers()` method you can use to remove unused identifiers. Note: You may need to call that multiple times if there are unused identifiers that referenced identifiers that were removed. See an example of dealing with that [here](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph/issues/590#issuecomment-479285956).