# Omnisharp for VS Code still doesn't seem to respect .editorconfig settings

Tags: c#, omnisharp, editorconfig

I am reading everywhere that Omnisharp now supports configuration from the `.editorconfig`. However, everything that I've tried does not seem to work. Here is the most slim test that I can come up with, but what is wrong here?

**omnisharp.json**

```
{
    "RoslynExtensionsOptions": {
        "enableAnalyzersSupport": true
    },
    "FormattingOptions": {
        "enableEditorConfigSupport": true
    }
}
```

**.editorconfig**

```
root = true

[*]
insert_final_newline = true
indent_size = 2
indent_style = tab
tab_width = 2
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
charset = utf-8

[*.cs]
csharp_new_line_before_else = true
```

**Program.cs**

```cs
using System;

namespace TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool isPostCrisis = true;

            if (isPostCrisis) {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Multiverse!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can see that `"enableAnalyzersSupport": true` rule is working, but I don't see any feed back for `csharp_new_line_before_else = true`.

[image]

I am using:

- VS Code v1.42.1
- C# extension for VS Code v1.21.12

  - Omnisharp server v1.34.13 (included through parent extension)

Here is a repo of the test project: https://github.com/roydukkey/moist/tree/stackoverflow/60607975

Comment: There is a new line before *else*.

Comment: @HansPassant I've updated the example and still don't see an error or warning.

Comment: It is not meant to generate an error, it helps you [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode).

Comment: In .NET 5 you can set the `EnableCodeStyleInBuild` option to true in the csproj file. In my editor, this also causes the style errors to be highlighted whereas otherwise they are not. Have you tried it with this setting? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#enforcecodestyleinbuild