# I would like to format my html code in VS Code

Tags: html, css, angular, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

my html code in my angular component, i automatically have :

```
     <a
        class="text-sm font-bold leading-relaxed inline-block mr-4 py-2 whitespace-no-wrap uppercase text-white"
        href="#pablo"
      >
        pink Color
      </a>
      <button
        class="cursor-pointer text-xl leading-none px-3 py-1 border border-solid border-transparent rounded bg-transparent block lg:hidden outline-none focus:outline-none"
        type="button"
      >
        <span class="block relative w-6 h-px rounded-sm bg-white"></span>
        <span
          class="block relative w-6 h-px rounded-sm bg-white mt-1"
        ></span>
        <span
          class="block relative w-6 h-px rounded-sm bg-white mt-1"
        ></span>
      </button>
```

While I would like that :

```
      <a class="text-sm font-bold leading-relaxed inline-block mr-4 py-2 whitespace-no-wrap uppercase text-white" href="#pablo">
        pink Color
      </a>
      <button class="cursor-pointer text-xl leading-none px-3 py-1 border border-solid border-transparent rounded bg-transparent block lg:hidden outline-none focus:outline-none" type="button">
        <span class="block relative w-6 h-px rounded-sm bg-white"></span>
        <span class="block relative w-6 h-px rounded-sm bg-white mt-1"></span>
        <span class="block relative w-6 h-px rounded-sm bg-white mt-1"></span>
      </button>
```

I search on my settings.json but i don't know where i can't change that... Any Suggestions ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode

Comment: If you're fine with third party solutions, I'd recommend this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify

Comment: Yes i know how to format a document, but how to change the behaviour of it ?

Answer (score 0):

For a better and current pattern, go in your extensions tab and download Prettier and ESLint.

So, in your settings you can add:

```
"[javascript, angular, html, css, json]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    },
    "eslint.quiet": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
    },
```

Or edit for any language you want to vscode act.

This will make the code always as readable as possible regardless of the length of the code line.

Comment: it does't work, my code always format in the wong way :/ Tks you

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution ! Add this lines in settings.json

```
"[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
}
```