# Wordpress site jeguery mobile responsive toggle menu not working

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, menu, toggle

on my website custom theme the mobile nav menu is not working. I believe it was done as a code with jquery bootstrap. I disabled all the plugins and it is still not working. Hire can someone take a look and let me know what could be wrong or a tool to input my site and it will

```js
< /head><body class="home page-template-default page page-id-18"><header class="dsfsdf"><nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top  u-not-logged-in"><div class="container"><div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" "><span class="
site - title ">The How And What <i>Nerd</i></span><br><span class="
site - tagline "></span></a></div><div id="
mainnav " class="
clearfix "><button type="
button " class="
navbar - toggle btn - menu " data-toggle="
collapse " data-target="#
navbar - collapse "><span class="
sr - only ">Toggle navigation </span><span class="
icon - bar "></span><span class="
icon - bar "></span><span class="
icon - bar "></span></button><nav id="
navbar - collapse " class="
collapse navbar - collapse "><div class="
menu - top - menu - container "><ul id="
menu - top - menu " class="
menu "><li id="
menu - item - 24116 " class="
menu - item menu - item - type - post_type menu - item - object - page menu - item - home current - menu - item page_item page - item - 18 current_page_item menu - item - 24116 "><a href=" /
  " aria-current="
page ">Home</a></li>
```

```css
</head><body class="home page-template-default page page-id-18"><header class="dsfsdf"><nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top  u-not-logged-in"><div class="container"><div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href=""><span class="site-title">The How And What<i>Nerd</i></span><br><span class="site-tagline"></span></a></div><div id="mainnav" class="clearfix"><button type="button" class="navbar-toggle btn-menu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation </span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button><nav id="navbar-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse"><div class="menu-top-menu-container"><ul id="menu-top-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-24116" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-18 current_page_item menu-item-24116"><a href="" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
```

here are the bootsrap:

/*  Enqueue Scripts Begin */

```
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.min.js', array(), null, false);

wp_deregister_script( 'bootstrap' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true);

/*  Enqueue Scripts End */

    /*  Enqueue Styles Begin */

wp_deregister_style( 'bootstrap' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', false, null, 'all');
```

Comment: You have syntax error in HTML. Reformat core and use some code editor to spot the problem.

Comment: Thank you Riki, any tool you recommend for reformatting core?

Comment: You can try it with `Visual Studio Code`. It is free text editor for programmers. Any good editor has this function.

Comment: Thanks again. I am new to this technical part. So just copy the bootstrap codes above and the ones in the snippet and post on the visual studio code?

Comment: Yes, paste code into VSCode editor and then issue command to reformat code - as said here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29973358/3137047