# TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined discord js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I know I'm not the best at this stuff and I'm still learning but can anyone help me with my error, I know it's with my "`let role =`" and it's something to do with the '`=`' sign, I'm just not sure what to change it to.

```js
if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_CHANNELS')) return message.reply(Embed3)
        if (!args[0]) return message.reply(Embed2)
        if (!message.mentions.channels.first()) return message.reply(Embed1)
        let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name = args[1]); //const role = message.mentions.roles.first
        if (!role) return message.reply(Embed4);
```

Current error is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined
```

I was following [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness), still not sure what to do though.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks and have a great day! :)

`EDIT 1`

In my index.js, I have this

--

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (command === 'lock') {
        client.commands.get('lock').execute(message, args)

    } else if (command === 'unlock') {
        client.commands.get('unlock').execute(message, args)
    }
})
```

`EDIT 2`

Stops printing after this line

```
 if (channel.name.startsWith('')) return message.reply(Embed5); console.log('All this works')

// STOPS PRINTING //
await message.mentions.channel.first.setName(`${channel.name}`);  // If channel name is not changed it's being rate limited. 
            try {
                await channel.updateOverwrite(role, {
                    SEND_MESSAGES: false
                }); 
                message.channel.send(Embed6);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
                message.channel.send(Embed7); 
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this code inside a `client.on('message', message => {` block?

Comment: In my index.js it is, this is in a ```module export  = {``` block, in my index.js it's this:

(changed it to above as it doesn't format, see original question)

Comment: This is causing the error `message.mentions.channels.first()`, try to console log each part of the object to see where it goes undefined. I think it's the mentions object that's undefined.

Comment: Ok I'll try that now

Comment: Ok, found it, it stops printing after this line (see above)

Answer (score 0):

So from what i read in the discord documentation

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=channels

and what i have seen in your code:

It may be that the mentions might not have a `channels` property set if there is no mention in differen channels. Therefore you might need to check for that:

```
if (message.mentions.channels || !message.mentions.channels.first()) return message.reply(Embed1)
```

Also the find you use is strange:

```
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name = args[1]);
```

This statement in the filter method will always set the name of the cache to args[1] and return the value. If args[1] is truthly, it will then return the first cache object.
what you need is a compare in this place

```
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == args[1]); // does not check type
or
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === args[1]); // checks type
```

Edit 2:

You might also need to check the way you access the `channel.first()` prop. `channel.first()` is a method. If you want the result of this method be shure to call it.

And handle the promise correctly with the `then` method. Since setName will teurn a Promise you need to embrace it!
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=setName

```
message.mentions.channels.first().setName(`${channel.name}`).then((result) => { // If channel name is not changed it's being rate limited.
    try {
        await channel.updateOverwrite(role, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false
        }); 
        message.channel.send(Embed6);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        message.channel.send(Embed7); 
    }
});
```

Also be shure to coretly inline your code and to check your controll structure. If you are using VScode use the format method: [How do you format code in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode)

Please try to read up on async / await statements in modern JS.
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

If you want to use await statement here, wrap it in a async function or use the `then` method to continue exec after processing.

Comment: It threw some errors because we're using await in a function, it doesn't pick up the async

`

   await channel.updateOverwrite(role, {
                    ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

`

Comment: Also I use VSCode Format Document plugin

Comment: Jea. this is true. if you dont know what async await does: It enables you to handle async calls as a row of sync calls: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function If you do not need to wait for this result tehen leave it or wrap it in a async method.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to js, how could I wrap this in an async function?

Comment: No Problem. But i guess i now get what you where trying to do ;)
with my code above just leave out the await.

Comment: I was wondering if you had discord, this is getting long and I need a bit more help, I cant make this a chat as I don't have enough experience to.

Comment: I am afraid this is not feasible. There are lots of great resources to learn JavaScript, and fully encourage you to also learning TypeScript, but i am not a teacher, and yes this question is getting out of hand XD

Comment: Yeah I agree I tried to put it in an async but it just keeps telling me that it's an invalid channel

Comment: Yea i looked it up, and saw that it should be `channels` instead of `chanel`

Comment: Sigh, still returns invalid channel, even when I mention it.

Comment: what channel is invalid? do you have an error and aline?

Comment: No errors, when I try to run my command "ss!lock #chat Members" it returns my message embed, "Please enter a valid channel"

Comment: This looks like a different problem then.

Comment: Agreed, not sure what to do anymore.

Comment: Well try to understand what part of you code is not working, provide a full minimal code sample, and get basic unserdanding of the language you are using. Otherwise we can not help anyone. There should not be a question like "write my code".

Answer (score -1):

I believe your mistake might have been attempting to find the first mentioned user in the channel. You would need to have used `.fetch()` for this. Make sure you respect your promise if you're using async!

If this isn't what you want and you simply want to find the first user that is mentioned in the message that the command is run on, you would need to use:

```js
        if (!message.mentions.users.first()) return message.reply(Embed1)
```

Comment: Oh, I should add a small example of fetching the messages
`const messageFetch = await message.channel.messages.fetch()`

Comment: Hi! Please see above comments, thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! (If this *does* solve the issue, be sure to mark it as answered)