# Is there a way to view JSON files automatically prettyfied in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, pretty-print

There are number of extensions in Visual Studio Code (VS Code) to prettify JSON files. But is there an extension or setting, which enables me to view all *.json files pre-formatted / pre prettified? I find it tedious to constantly press shift-alt-F + ctrl-s when viewing ugly one line json-data, especially if the content of the file is being updated regularly back to pre-formatted form.

Answer (score 79):

```
On Windows:    Shift + Alt + F  
On Mac:        Shift + Option + F  
On Linux:      Ctrl + Shift + I
```

Original answer [How do you format code in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode)

I'm adding it here because when I was looking for it I found your post before the other one. Hope it helps.

Comment: The ideal solution to the original question would not involve pressing any key combos. Nonetheless thanks for leaving this documenting answer!

Comment: I get there is not formateer for binary text file installed message

Answer (score 2):

You can download JsonPrettifier extension.

Comment: Unless this automatically format the file upon opening, it does not answer the original question

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that if you have the setting

```
JSON > format: Keep Lines
```

enabled (the default is disabled), that a one-liner JSON file (or any JSON that has multiple key/values on the same line) will not be formatted as you wish.  The file might not change at all until you disable the `Keep Lines` setting and re-format.