# How to fix a formatting problem in VS code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I just pressed "crtl" + "s" and it appeared like this. May i ask what problem i am encountering?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbd5f.png)

Comment: If you hover over the first squiggly red line, does it give you an indication of what is wrong?

Comment: It shows "Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for 'button'." Are you saying this?

Comment: If you remove the space between `<` and `/` everywhere, does it stop complaining?

Comment: Yes, but it is meaningless, the code is fine originally. I just want to make it look nicer by formatting it when saving, and it turns out like this.

Comment: what formatter are you using currently?

Comment: Can you check this once.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode

Comment: Where can check which formatter i am using?  I typed "format" on the setting, it showed None for Default Formatter.

Comment: I know the shortcut of formatting, and i am using Ubuntu. I have checked it and what you are suggesting?