# Is there any shortcut/hotkey in vscode to format attributes of an html element

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, element

I have this code of element, and i need to format the attributes from this:

```
<input class="cool-input" id="input" value="test" placeholder="test" />
```

to

```
<input class="cool-input"
  id="input"
  value="test"
  placeholder="test"
/>
```

but I didn't find any hotkey to do it. Is there any, and if there is, what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this setting:

`HTML > Format: Wrap Attributes` set to `force`

and then select your line:

`<input class="cool-input" id="input" value="test" placeholder="test" />`

and trigger the command `Format Selection` and you will get:

```html
<input class="cool-input"
  id="input"
  value="test"
  placeholder="test" />
```

Comment: Does this work in React?

Answer (score 0):

The Prettierextension is the best way to format codes.

Answer (score -1):

Check this thread
[Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode/29973358#29973358)

Installing an VSCode extension can help too.
Here's one
[Prettier – Code formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)

Can be set up to format on save and Format on selection.
The Doc has a very detailed how to guide.

Comment: This thing formats the whole document, but I need to format only 1 document, so first method is irrelevant, and if second method, then what extension?

Comment: @rllynotfox, how do you mean whole document? It only gets to format on-save, that is, when you save the current file you're on, not all the documents.

Comment: Sorry my grammar died when I wrote it

Comment: why would anyone put an arrow down, on this, I use prettier and I love it, also depending how you just format yourself in the code, prettier sometimes adapts to it like how writer haves it here. What is wrong with people these days