# Prettier extension, but for C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I've got used to VSC clean up my code, while working with React. Now that I'm using C#, I'm not able to find anything like prettier for this language. I'm looking for some way of setting up my VSCode to do this for me, stuff like: removing white spaces, adding semicolons after each end of the code snippet, broke the lines if the code line was too long (like a long array or parameters). Is there any way for that or was it just one of bonuses of writing in javascript?

Comment: Maybe this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode

Comment: What do you mean add semicolons?

Comment: Asking for favorite tools/resources is off-topic. There are plenty of code formatters for C# (which you presumably already looked at after https://www.bing.com/search?q=Prettier+extension%2C - make sure to include results of your research when moving the question to likely more appropriate [softwarerecs.se] site), but you seem to be asking for something else. As @Blindy pointed out it is very unclear what you expect such extension should do - do you need it to fix syntax errors in the code automatically ("add semicolon" )?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I meant when I was using Prettier (and maybe part of it was TSLint?) in React it formatted my code automatically, meaning stuff like: removing white spaces, adding semicolons after each end of the code snippet, broke the lines if the code line was too long (like a long array or parameters) and it did it automatically after a save. Just organized code in a standardized way so it has the same structure no matter how I wrote it, even if I wrote it all in one line. You're right, I've searched for something like this for free on Google, didn't find it.

Comment: Also just wanted to add, that like automatic change from single to double quotes and always adding space after comma and stuff like that

Answer (score 2):

[Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), [Code Maid](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveCadwallader.CodeMaid) Probably others as well