# Visual Studio Code: Menu Bar: Show All Commands

Tags: visual-studio-code, usability, discoverability

How do I add a command to Visual Studio Code's menu bar to make the feature more discoverable? I don't see a menu bar or toolbar editor like [Microsoft Office's Quick Access Toolbar dialog](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-quick-access-toolbar-43fff1c9-ebc4-4963-bdbd-c2b6b0739e52).

For example, the [product's documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_formatting) says that the user should format source code by pressing a keyboard combination, typing a phrase into the Command Palette, or right-clicking in the Editor and using the context menu.

As of June 17, 2022, 988 people on StackOverflow said "[How do you format code in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode)" is a good question, which indicates that the feature is hard to find. The documentation implies that users ought to memorize all the keyboard combinations or memorize all the magic phrases for the Command Palette.

I'm using Visual Studio Code version 1.69.1 on Windows 10.