# Best way to write razor (format issue)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I have the following code in razor:

```
@{
                foreach (var item in this.Model)
                {
                    if (item.Items == null)
                    {
                        @: <li @{if (item.Active) { <text> class="active" </text>   } }>

                       if (item.SpanClass == null)
                       {
                            @: <a href="@item.Url" @{ if (item.Active) { <text> class="waves-effect active" </text>    } else { <text> class="waves-effect" </text>     } }><i class="@item.Icon"></i><span> @item.Text </span></a>
                       }else
                       {
                            @: <a href="@item.Url" @{ if (item.Active) { <text> class="waves-effect active" </text>    } else { <text> class="waves-effect" </text>     } }><i class="@item.Icon"></i><span> @item.Text <span class="@item.SpanClass">@item.SpanValue</span></span></a>
                                        }

                        }
                        @: </li>
                     }
            }
```

It looks like this:

[image]

But I go to:

[image]

Then the code format is destroyed:

[image]

> Any clue?

Comment: You can simplify all this considerably by using a view model that includes properties for your class names - e.g. `<li class="@item.ClassName">` where `ClassName` is either "active" or `null` (in the case of `null`, then class name will be omitted from the html)

Comment: For the link it would be `<a href="@item.Url" class="waves-effect @Model.ClassName" ...`

Comment: This might be of some  help http://stackoverflow.com/a/4942145/1339516

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like that

```
@{
    foreach (var item in this.Model)
    {
    var activeClass = item.Active ? "active" : "";
    if (item.Items == null)
    {
        <li class="@activeClass">
            @if (item.SpanClass == null)
            {

                <a href="@item.Url" class="waves-effect @activeClass"><i class="@item.Icon"></i><span> @item.Text </span></a>
            }
            else
            {
                <a href="@item.Url" class="waves-effect @activeClass"><i class="@item.Icon"></i><span> @item.Text <span class="@item.SpanClass">@item.SpanValue</span></span></a>
            }
        </li>
      }
   }
}
```