# Splitting lines of code in Visual Studio 2017 / Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017, hotkeys

I was watching a tutorial where they were using Eclipse instead of VS. In that tutorial, they had a line simular to the following example:

`if (true){ example = 1; DoSomething(); x = ReturnNumber(); break; }`

Using a hotkey they split the line of code, one line at the time, to

```
if (true)
{
    example = 1;
    DoSomething();
    x = ReturnNumber();
    break;
}
```

I can't find out what the hotkey for this is since I don't know how to describe it. So, what's the hotkey for it?

Edit:
[image]

Comment: C#? try ctrl+E, D

Comment: Tried it, and that isn't it. Ctrl E seems to compile a selected block of code - or line if you haven't selected anything - and Ctrl D duplicates the line. Very useful hotkeys though.

Comment: i doubt you're using visual studio. because ctrl+D to duplicate is the way netbeans(intellij idea, pycharm) do.  how about menu Edit-Advanced-Format(the last word i don't remember)

Comment: I think you possibly meant ctrl K, D. Ctrl E, D is not recognized as a command so I tried them separately, resulting in the commands above. Ctrl K, D reformats the code.

Comment: can you paste a screen shot of your menu to the question? i don't believe.

Comment: Added the screenshot. It's a fresh installment of VS 2017, no hotkeys are swapped.

Comment: i searched and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942113/format-code-shortcut-for-visual-studio), both of our short keys are valid...